# At which point in the series should I watch the The Last: Naruto the Movie and Boruto: Naruto the Movie?

Tags: naruto

Okay, so I just recently watched episode 441 of the English sub of Naruto, and I was wondering whether I had caught up enough to watch *The Last: Naruto the Movie* and *Boruto: Naruto the Movie*?

Could someone tell me after which episode should I watch them?

Comment: (spoiler free comment, I swear)
I haven't seen that film yet, but if the title is an indicative then you haven't clearly catched up to it. Boruto refers to a character belonging to the sequel of Naruto.
Meaning? You won't catch with that film til you read the whole manga/ see the anime. Now enjoy and focus on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Last: Naruto the Movie take place after the [Manga chapter 700](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Uzumaki!!_(chapter_700)). And if I'm not wrong episode [441](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Returning_Home) is a filler and not part of main manga story that takes someplace after [chapter 678 of manga](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/My_Will_Is). So you need to read the manga from 678 to 699 before watching The Last: Naruto the Movie, or you can wait for the anime to reach the point of chapter 699.

After that Naruto Manga chapter 700 take place, which act like epilogue.

Boruto: Naruto the Movie take place after Manga chapter 700 and [Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Gaiden:_The_Seventh_Hokage_and_the_Scarlet_Spring)
, Gaiden is a mini manga series that takes place between chapter 700 and Boruto movie. Gaiden can be skipped but

> You will miss how Sarada Uchiha accepted her family.

But I will definitely suggest to watch anime till it reaches chapter 699 before both the film, or read the rest of the story in the manga. Skipping gaiden is your choice, except about a character mentioned in spoiler.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually your personal opinion, but I think you are far enough to watch The Last. You can watch Boruto if you want right now or wait until you finish the series. If you finished the manga then go ahead and watch Boruto, but if you didn't then it will be better to do it.

Answer (score -1):

It will be best to wait until after episode 493, I just watched it and now I'm watching The Last and I think this movie goes very well with the times after that episode.

Comment: You should qualify why you *think* it "goes very well". Also "goes very well" is not descriptive. I could claim it "goes very well" with episode 494 and we'll just have as many answers as episodes in this case.